# Permutations and Combinations in arranging letters

Tags: permutations

Number of ways to arrange the letters $(A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C,D,E,E,F)$ such that no two $C's$ are together ?

**My solution:**

I calculated all possibilities with CC together i.e $\dfrac{14!}{5!3!2!}$ and subtracted it from total i.e $\dfrac{15!}{5!3!3!2!}$.

But my answer is wrong. Why?

Comment: There are three types where 2 or more C are together, namely CCbbbbC,CbbbbCC,CCC. (the bbbb meaning at least one non-C between.

Comment: @coffeemath The \* is used for italics. Use `\*` instead, or surround the whole expression with backticks ( \` ) to get, for instance, `CC*C`

Comment: @Arthur Thanks-- didn't know that. (too late to change comment..)

Comment: Can you tell me what is the answer plz

Answer (score 0):

Because the combinations where all three `C` are adjacent were mishandled: each case of `CC C` was counted separately from all the cases of `C CC`, when in reality they're the same. You therefore need to subtract once all different combinations that have all three `C`'s together to get the correct number of combinations where at least two `C`'s are together.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Let us denote the three $C$'s by $C_1, C_2, C_3$. There are $4$ possible ways of these $C$'s coming together: $C_1C_2, C_2C_3, C_1C_3, C_1C_2C_3$. I hope you will now be able to continue.

Answer (score 0):

12 alphabets without C's can be arranged in 12! ways. ...(A)

We can arrange 3 C's in any of the 13 (=12+1) positions marked as * below.

$* 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 * 10 * 11 * 12 * 13 * $

(where 1, 2… 13 represent remaining alphabets)

This can be done in C(13,3) ways. ......(B)

From (A) and (B), required number of ways

$= \frac{12! × C(13,3)}{5! × 3! ×2!}$

$= \frac{12! × 13!}{10! × 3! × 5! × 3! ×2!}$

Comment: If you are using the "gap" method, you would first permute the **non-C's,** and place the C's in the gaps. Furthermore, you appear to have taken the C's as distinct instead of identical.

Comment: @true blue anil so what changes I have to made?

Comment: $\dfrac{12!}{5!3!1!2!1!}\times\binom{13}{3}$

Comment: Why 12! ? We have 13 places to fill C's.

Comment: The first part is permuting the non-C's. The second part is placing the 3 C's in any 3 of 13 places available

Comment: Ok got it. Thank u so much.

Comment: Is it fine now?

Comment: The C's are identical, so $C(13,3) \equiv \binom{13}3$, not $P(13,3)$

Comment: Thank you. And if still any problem in my answer you can edit my answer or post your own  answer. After all we all have same motive to help someone.